# Does Hive preserve map keys order?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm working with Hive Map Type and I'm wondering how does Hive handles key-values pairs order?

**Example**:
Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE db.my_table (col MAP<STRING, INT>)

INSERT INTO db.my_table
SELECT map('A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3)
UNION ALL
SELECT map('C', 4, 'B', 5, 'A', 6)
```

Will every `SELECT` statement return the same order of key-value pairs (from my tests they're always in original order)?

```
SELECT col FROM db.my_table

{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}
{"C":4,"B":5,"A":6}
```

What about `map_values()` and `map_keys()` (they also seem to preserve original order)?

```
SELECT map_values(col), map_keys(col) FROM db.my_table

[1,2,3] | ["A","B","C"]
[4,5,6] | ["C","B","A"]
```

I'm also using Brickhouse `MapFilterKeysUDF` and the result seems to be sorted by keys. Is that always the case?

```
ADD jar hdfs://.../brickhouse-0.6.0.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION filter_map AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.MapFilterKeysUDF';

SELECT filter_map(col, array('C', 'B')) FROM db.my_table

{"B":2,"C":3}
{"B":5,"C":4}
```

**To sum up**:
I have 3 main questions (but would really appreciate a more complex explanation):

- Does every `SELECT` statement return the original order of MAP?
- Do `map_values()` and `map_keys()` follow the same convention?
- What is the order of Brickhouse `MapFilterKeysUDF` results?